# Put a condition with use-position (hook)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I have this code :

```
import { usePosition } from 'use-position';

export const myfunc = (props) => {
    const {latitude, longitude, error} = usePosition();
return (...)
};
```

I would like to do something like this :

```
if(i=0){
     const {latitude, longitude, error} = usePosition();
}
```

But like usePosition is an Hook it does not work...

I mean I would like to use just one time this usePosition() because I just need when I launch my app.

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: this violates rules-of-hooks https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: Hooks can only be called from the body of a functional component or other hooks. They can't be called conditionally or in loops. Rules of hooks.

Comment: Ok but is there a way to call just one time this hook ? Then disable it ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call hooks inside a condition or loop.

You can restructure your component like this (assuming 'i' comes from props):

```
export const myfunc = (props) => {
  const { latitude, longitude, error } = usePosition();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.i === 0) {
      // perform an action
    }
  }, [
    props.i(/* or even a state value will work */),
    latitude,
    longitude,
    error,
  ]);

  return (...);
};
```